# Why recurse function update data?

Tags: function, recursion

Following recurse example. can you please apply, why b[] array data update at each hirarchy of recurse, while , to my knolegde it should not update, at rise to another hierarchy level. Tnx

recursive function
main function

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  

void fun(int a[], int b[2], int n)  
{  
    if (n == 2)  
    {  
        b[0] = a[0];  
        b[1] = a[1];  
        if (a[0]>a[1])  
        {  
            b[0] = a[1];  
            b[1] = a[0];  
        }  
    }  
    else  
        fun(a, b, n - 1);  //insert function
    if (b[0]<a[n - 1])  
    {  
        if (b[1]<a[n - 1])  
        {  
            b[0] = b[1];  
            b[1] = a[n - 1];  
        }  
        else  
            b[0] = a[n - 1];  
    }  
}  

int main()  //insert main
{  
    int arr[] = { 12,10,30,50,20,100 };  
    int b[2];  
    fun(arr, b, 6);  //insert function
    printf("%d\n", b[0]);  
    system("pause");  
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: Exactly why do you think that `b` should not be updated?

Comment: Because in other programming languages you can pass an array by value, which is not possible in c. At least not straight-forward; it might be possible, however, to achieve the same behaviour after wrapping the array into a struct, which indeed _can_ be passed by value then.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass array by value to recursive function possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16094009/pass-array-by-value-to-recursive-function-possible)

Comment: Exactly, but at above example no struct involved. still array b pass by value and i want to understand why.